# What (if any) path for OpenNI should show up in environmental variables

Tags: cmake, environment-variables, kinect, openni, point-cloud-library

I recently had it pointed out to me that I might have OpenNI installed correctly but PCL is unable to access it. I've been trying to use various packages with the Kinect and when cmake compiling I always encounter the same error:

```
-- checking for module 'openni-dev'

-- package 'openni-dev' not found

-- Could NOT find openni (missing: OPENNI_INCLUDE_DIRS)

** WARNING ** io features related to openni will be disabled
```

I used printenv and received this output:

```
printenv
SSH_AGENT_PID=2570
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/tmp/keyring-xXJFL7/gpg:0:1
TERM=xterm
SHELL=/bin/bash
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/hydro/share/ros
XDG_SESSION_COOKIE=aa6e36316433d5c21f6f3b1500000008-1400098211.848077-377195861
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/hydro/share
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
WINDOWID=56623110
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/tmp/keyring-xXJFL7
USER=robot2
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/ros/hydro/lib
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
CPATH=/opt/ros/hydro/include
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/keyring-xXJFL7/ssh
SESSION_MANAGER=local/robot2-Precision-T7600:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/2535,unix/robot2-Precision-T7600:/tmp/.ICE-unix/2535
DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg
PATH=/opt/ros/hydro/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu
PWD=/home/robot2
GNOME_KEYRING_PID=2524
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path
UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=libappmenu.so
COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE=ubuntu
GDMSESSION=ubuntu
SHLVL=1
HOME=/home/robot2
ROS_DISTRO=hydro
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated
PYTHONPATH=/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
LOGNAME=robot2
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-DdLQNdIXso,guid=2440d412c31af4bd219f648600000030
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/ros/hydro/lib/pkgconfig
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/ros/hydro
DISPLAY=:0.0
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/hydro/etc/ros
COLORTERM=gnome-terminal
XAUTHORITY=/home/robot2/.Xauthority
_=/usr/bin/printenv
```

Does anyone have any ideas?  Is this potentially a path issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have installed OpenNI into some non-standard ocation, that's why CMake can't locate it. Help it by setting `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to the dir where OpenNI's `include/` is located.

Comment: A thousand times thank you.  I wish I could upvote your answer.  This is exactly what worked.  I simply added the OpenNI path with prefix, and although the "openni-dev not found" still showed it compiled correctly when using cmake.  Kinect input achieved successfully.